# Dart: Flutter: Gradle: Execution failed for task ':vibrate:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

!!Please Help!!
This was the terminal console after running flutter build apk and using package vibrate: ^0.0.4 (which is where the error seems to be ocurring): https://pub.dev/packages/vibrate

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- **What went wrong:**
  Execution failed for task ':vibrate:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fbb4dd3de4ec7ae76283ad46c719d5a1/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

```
 /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fbb4dd3de4ec7ae76283ad46c719d5a1/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
                                                                    
 /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fbb4dd3de4ec7ae76283ad46c719d5a1/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
                                                                    
 /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fbb4dd3de4ec7ae76283ad46c719d5a1/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
                                                                    
 /Users/.../.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/fbb4dd3de4ec7ae76283ad46c719d5a1/core-1.1.0/res/values/values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

- **Try:**
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 21s
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done
> 22.3s The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the
> incompatibility. Building plugin path_provider... Running Gradle task
> 'assembleAarRelease'...                              Running Gradle
> task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    1.6s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'path_provider'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

The plugin path_provider could not be built due to the issue above.

Thanks!